# How to read the header in the web server response

Tags: java, xml, soap

Tell me how to read the header in the web server's response via the `@WebMethod` and `@WebResult` annotations. Of course, I can do this by SOAPConnection and parsing SOAPMessage, but there is a lot of functionality on javax.jws and I would like to unify everything. I need value from `<osb:Backend/>`.

Server response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <osb:Backend xmlns:osb="http://osb.emias.mos.ru/system">СКУУ</osb:Backend>
        <ipaddr xmlns="https:/bis.skyy.soapHeader/">10.0.5.147</ipaddr>
        <build xmlns="https:/bis.skyy.soapHeader/">1ec22a8</build>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <getEmployeePacketInfoResponse2 xmlns="http://emias.gov.ru/medempregisterservicetypes/1" xmlns:ns1="http://emias.gov.ru/types/1" xmlns:ns0="http://emias.gov.ru/servicetypes/1">
            <EmployeeList>
.......
```

Interface declaration:

```
@WebResult(name = "Backend", targetNamespace = "http://emias.gov.ru/medempregisterservicetypes/1", partName = "getMedicalEmployeePacketInfo")
@WebMethod
public String getMedicalEmployeePacketInfo2(
    @WebParam(partName = "getMedicalEmployeePacketInfoRequest", name = "getEmployeePacketInfoRequest", targetNamespace = "http://emias.gov.ru/medempregisterservicetypes/1")
    GetEmployeePacketInfoRequest getMedicalEmployeePacketInfoRequest
) throws FaultMessage;
```

Request class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "requesterSystemCode",
    "healthOrgID",
    "employeeList"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "getEmployeePacketInfoRequest")
public class GetEmployeePacketInfoRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "RequesterSystemCode", required = true)
    protected String requesterSystemCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "HealthOrgID")
    protected String healthOrgID;
    @XmlElement(name = "EmployeeList", required = true)
    protected GetEmployeePacketInfoRequest.EmployeeList employeeList;
....
```

Request example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://emias.gov.ru/medempregisterservicetypes/1">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>SPU/erz</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">emias_erz</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:getEmployeePacketInfoRequest2>
            <ns:RequesterSystemCode>SPU</ns:RequesterSystemCode>
            <ns:HealthOrgID>10000430</ns:HealthOrgID>
            <ns:EmployeeList>
                <ns:EmployeeID>21426012</ns:EmployeeID>
            </ns:EmployeeList>
        </ns:getEmployeePacketInfoRequest2>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. I haven't used jws, and haven't tried this, but it may help:**

Try to add `header` option to your `@WebResult` annotation.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jws/WebResult.html :

```
public abstract boolean header
```

> "If true, the result is pulled from a message header rather then the message body."

But seems like in order to do so you have to write appropriate class for JAXB (I'm not sure).

**2. Instead, I did it straightforward, and used this method:**

Your business data is located inside message body - between `<getEmployeePacketInfoRequest2/>` tags. This is what JAXB creates your `GetEmployeePacketInfoResponse` class objects from. So, if you want to obtain anything outside this tags, you have to get it from the whole SOAP response. But you don't need to parse it manually - javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage has inbuilt `getSOAPHeader()` method, which does what you need. Then just transform it to DOM, and do `getElementsByTagName()` or `getElementsByTagNameNS()`.

Comment: 1. I tried, but unfortunately it did not help.
2. So now I am doing it, but I would like to be through annotations, but something never found examples. Requests with header through the annotations are created, but did not find a single example of getting the headers from the answers (((

Answer (score 0):

implemented the second sentence

```
import lombok.val;
.... 
val soapPart = resp.getSOAPPart();
            val soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            val soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
            val backendNode = soapHeader.getElementsByTagName("osb:Backend");
            if (backendNode.getLength() > 0) {
                backend = backendNode.item(0).getTextContent();
            }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use annotated parameter in your class method like this:

```
    @WebResult(name = "Backend", targetNamespace = "http://emias.gov.ru/medempregisterservicetypes/1", partName = "getMedicalEmployeePacketInfo")
    @WebMethod
    public String getMedicalEmployeePacketInfo2(
        @WebParam(partName = "header", name = "ipaddr", targetNamespace = "https:/bis.skyy.soapHeader/", header = true, mode = WebParam.Mode.IN)
        String header,
...
        @WebParam(partName = "getMedicalEmployeePacketInfoRequest", name = "getEmployeePacketInfoRequest", targetNamespace = "http://emias.gov.ru/medempregisterservicetypes/1")
        GetEmployeePacketInfoRequest getMedicalEmployeePacketInfoRequest
    ) throws FaultMessage;
```

pay attention to `header = true` and `mode = WebParam.Mode.IN`